# Assigning value to vector index

Tags: c++, vector, stl

This is the part of my code. I am assigning values to vector v by two different ways. while it is working fine with k[0]=a and k[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDT9G.png)=b but When i am using push_back function then the vector k returns value 0. what is the difference between these two?

---

```
 class Solution{   
    public:
        vector<int> sumClosest(vector<int>arr, int x)
        {
            // code here
            int l=0,r,dif=INT_MAX,a,b;
            vector<int> k(2);
            r=arr.size()-1 ;
            while((l<r) and (l>=0) and (r<=arr.size()-1))
            {
                if(abs(arr[l]+arr[r]-x) <dif)
                {
                    a=arr[l];
                    b=arr[r];
                    dif=abs(arr[l]+arr[r]-x);
                }
                
                if((arr[l]+arr[r]) <x)
                l++;
                else r--;
            }
            
            k.push_back(a);
            k.push_back(b);
cout<<k[0]<<" "<<k[1]<<endl;
            k[0]=a;
            k[1]=b;
            cout<<k[0]<<" "<<k[1]<<endl;
            return k;
            
        }
    };
```

---

[image]

Comment: `push_back` increases the size of the vector and modifies the last indexed value, while the direct index assigning is not.

Comment: `r<=arr.size()-1` is just `r < arr.size()`.

Comment: @김선달 incresing vector size is not helping here.

Comment: @sweenish r is not affecting the vector element value

Comment: When declared, `k` has a size of 2. Those first two elements are initialized with 0. `push_back()` *adds new elements* to `k`. `k` now has a size of 4 because of 2 push_backs.

Comment: My note about `r` is an obvious nitpick. You're over-thinking.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230993/discussion-between-proton-and-sweenish).

Comment: @Proton -- [You should read the documentation on what push_back does](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By doing the following, you are making a vector whose size is 2, and every element in the vector will be initialized to 0.

```
vector<int> k(2);
```

By using the `push_back` method, you are pushing a new element to the back of the vector, which effectively increases the size of the vector increase by 1.

If you want to push two values so that they are stored in `k[0]` and `k[1]`, you must initialize the vector empty, which can be achieved by doing:

```
vector<int> k;
```